# Isoband and its strong reverse dependencies will be archive if you do not "negociate the necessary actions"

Tags: r, dependency-management

A recent message from the CRAN team involving the archival of the package `ìsoband` mention that all those package relying on this one will also be archived:

> archiving this will necessitate also archiving its CRAN strong reverse
> dependencies

However, I checked in my DESCRIPTION file and `isoband` is not part of my own package's dependencies. So I am assuming that my package relies on a package which itself relies on `isoband`.

How can I identify which of the package in my DESCRIPTION file itself depends on `isoband`?

I have seen functions and packages such as `revdepcheck` but none works at this time.

Comment: Although `isoband` is not a direct dependency of your package (you don't put it in `Imports` in the DESCRIPTION), it is an indirect one because it is a dependency of `ggplot2`, which you import. Therefore, if `isoband` is archived, then this threatens `ggplot2` and indirectly your package. The maintainers of `ggplot2` and `isoband` said on Twitter they were going to fix the issue during the week so you shouldn't have to do anything

Comment: Thank you for these reassuring words. I hope the R core team realizes that such mass emails are not reassuring and provides bad advertisements for R.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you may have to do something to fix your package once `isoband` will be fixed. I suppose there will be a new release of `ggplot2` to explicitely depend on the last version of `isoband`, and you should in turn depend on the last version of `ggplot2`. But that's a bit of speculation, I think you should follow what Thomas Lin Pedersen (main developer of `ggplot2`) says on Twitter. There will probably be some communication coming from the `tidyverse` team in general.

Comment: For anyone else frantically searching around this morning, here is the link to the [relevant tweet](https://twitter.com/thomasp85/status/1577559610898120704?cxt=HHwWgICwufOGz-QrAAAA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `pak::pkg_deps_explain()` allows you to find the connection between your package and `isoband`:

```r
pak::pkg_deps_explain("superb", "isoband")
#> superb -> ggplot2 -> isoband
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the clear and quick response!